# method links does not exist - laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, search

I am using filter by serial number in table,, but when I click the button error like this

> " method links does not exist"

this is my controller

```
 public function show(Request $request)
{

    $instrument = Instrument::when($request->serial_number, function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('serial_number', 'like', "%{$request->serial_number}%");
    })->paginate(5);
    $instrument->appends($request->only('serial_number'));
    return view('settinginstrument.index', compact('settinginstrument'));
}
```

this is my blade:

```
 <table class="table">
    @foreach ($instruments as $instrument)
      <tr>
        <td>
          Serial Number : {{ $instrument->serial_number }}
          @if($instrument->customer !== NULL)
          <div class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-hospital-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>  {{ $instrument->customer->name }}</div>
          @endif
          @if($instrument->contractType !== NULL)
          <div class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-compress" aria-hidden="true"></i>  {{ $instrument->contractType->name }}</div>
          @endif
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="pull-right">
            <a type="button" href="{{ route('instrument.edit', ['instrumentType' => $instrumentType->id, 'instrument' => $instrument->id]) }}"
              class="btn btn-success ">
              <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit
            </a>
              @if($instrument->customer == NULL || $instrument->contractType == NULL)
              <a href="{{ route('instrument.destroy', ['instrumentType' => $instrumentType->id, 'instrument' => $instrument->id]) }}"
                data-method="delete" data-confirm="" class="btn btn-danger">
                <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> <span class="hidden-xs">Delete</span>
              </a>
              @endif

          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    @endforeach
  </table>
  <div class="paginator text-center">{{ $instruments->links() }}</div>
  @else
....................................
```

where wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

When you have zero counts of record and you are trying to access the links() then such issue occurs 
Add on condition to check the record exists.

```
@if($instruments)
<div class="paginator text-center">{{ $instruments->links() }}</div>
@endif
```

Also in the controller you have one typo error `$instruments` and `$instrument`
I recommend that add the condition above the `foreach`
and on blank result show some message that **record not found**.

**Update**
Also pass the `$instruments` to the balde

```
$instruments = Instrument::when($request->serial_number, function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->where('serial_number', 'like', "%{$request->serial_number}%");
})->paginate(5);
$instruments->appends($request->only('serial_number'));
return view('settinginstrument.index', compact('instruments'));
```

Comment: stop copying my answer.

Comment: @LeoinstanceofKelmendi I have specially mention Update also the whole answer and the time you can check

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the param to the view:

```
public function show(Request $request)
{

    $instruments = Instrument::when($request->serial_number, function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('serial_number', 'like', "%{$request->serial_number}%");
    })->paginate(5);
    $instrument->appends($request->only('serial_number'));
    return view('settinginstrument.index',['instruments' => $instruments);
}
```

Then on the blade:

```
{{$instruments->links()}}
```

Comment: same as,, not can and still eroor